# Angular Material: Add sidenav to just a few pages?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want a subset of pages of my site to have sidebar navigation.

So, the home page and others would not have any sidebar, but one section of the site would have a sidebar. On that section, users can click on sidebar menu items to navigate to different pages within that section.

This is the same structure as Angular Material uses on its main site.

If you go to the [home page](https://material.angular.io/), there is no sidebar. But, if you go to the [components page](https://material.angular.io/components/categories), there is a sidebar, and you can click on sidebar menu items to navigate within the components section of the site.

How can I accomplish this structure using Angular Material's sidenav component?

Here are some more details in case helpful:

The documents say that mat-sidebar is for adding a sidebar to the whole site, and that mat-drawer is just for one section, so I assume I would use mat-drawer. But I don't find any examples of implementation for adding sidebar nav to one section. The tricky part is efficient code that enables me to navigate among different routes in the given section.

The basic code is like this:

html:

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
  <mat-drawer mode="side" opened>Drawer content</mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content>Main content</mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Often, you put this in app.component.html, and put in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` where "Main Content" is in the code.

How do you do this when the sidebar navigation should not be for the whole site's router-outlet, but just the routes for particular components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the main `app.component` (surrounded by whatever other pieces of mark-up you want there)

Define some routing that has your sub-section (either lazy-loaded or not):

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'one', component: Page1Component },
    { path: 'two', component: Page2Component },
    {
        path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, children: [
            { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
            { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent }
        ]
    },
];
```

The `Home`, `Page1` and `Page2` and whatever... are just normal component pages and don't have a sidebar.

In `AdminComponent` put your `sidenav`:

```
<h1>Admin</h1>
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
        <mat-action-list>
                <mat-list-item [routerLink]="['dashboard']">Dashboard</mat-list-item>
                <mat-list-item [routerLink]="['users']">Users</mat-list-item>
        </mat-action-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content><router-outlet></router-outlet></mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Sidenav is then only in existence when under the `admin` route.

Comment: Thanks. This is it. The usage of child routes opens up a lot structure wise.

Answer (score 0):

Use the material sidenav API, you can make it open or closed based on your needs with a variable on the input property [opened] like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" [opened]="boolean_var | async">Sidenav content</mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

        <br>

        <button routerLink="/without" [state]="{ open: false }">
            Page Without Sidenav
        </button>

        <br>

        <button routerLink="/with" [state]="{ open: true }">
            Page with Sidenav
        </button>

     </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

now it's up to you to decide how to synchronize the variable with the page routing.

There are more ways, for example, you could pass a value on routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'with', component: WithSidenavComponent, data: { open : true } },
  { path: 'without', component: WithoutSidenavComponent , data: { open : false }},
];
```

and set your root component like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.boolean_var = this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map( (response: NavigationEnd) => this.router.config.find( conf => conf.path == response.url.slice(1) ).data.open || false )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean put the mat-sidenav-container on app.component.html, and just keep it closed for the entire app except the few pages where I want the sidebar to appear?

Comment: Yes, I think it's the best approach

Comment: Thanks. But given that the sidebar is just a portion of the site, I think the better answer is to use child routes. So there will be one parent page in that section, which has the mat-drawer code on it. And then there are child routes that are added to that page depending on what is clicked on in the sidebar. I'm working on this now, and can post the solution in the next few days.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my answer, there is only one parent container with the sidenav and so many child routes that based on where they are, they show or not the sidenav based on your variable.

Comment: I added a stackblitz for you : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qz2tj8

Comment: Thanks. Your way can work, but I'd prefer to not be loading the sidenav where it will never appear (even if it is set to "closed"). The goal was a structure where the sidenav is only loaded on the particular section of the site that is relevant. Loading the sidenav on the parent component of that section (instead of the app.component of the whole site), and then using child routing to load children on that component, accomplishes this.

Comment: This is an applicable answer but I find it a bit taxing when I have to use multiple sidenavs for different types of users. I mean its possible but its a little too much work